# Authenticate user without using angularfire

Tags: node.js, express, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an application in which i need to authenticate user. I am using `firebase` for database. I have used `node.js` for getting data from `firebase`. Now all i want is to create *login page* and in that i need to authenticate user by their email address and password. And i want to use the same method how i am fetching the data that is using `node` and i don't want to use `angularfire` for the authentication. Is it possible to perform? If it is can you please share how can i accomplish that?

Comment: Are you asking how to sign the user in to Firebase with email/password from a node.js process?

Comment: Yes .. is it possible @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating from a server-side process with the Firebase 3.x SDK requires the use of a service account. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#server-sdk-authentication):

> When you authenticate a server, rather than sign in with a user account's credentials as you would in a client app, you authenticate with a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) which identifies your server to Firebase.

If you want to custom handle the authentication of your users, you'd [create a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens) for your users on the server and then [have them pass that to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

In general I'd recommend reading this [article about common application architectures when using the Firebase Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html).